# Name for the following auto-regressive type data generating model

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, vector-autoregression

Suppose $X$ is a $d$-dimensional random vector. The coordinates follow an auto-regressive structure:

$$
X_{1} \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^2_1), \qquad X_{j}|X_{< j} \sim N(a^T_j X_{<j},~ \sigma^2_j), \qquad a_j \in \mathbb{R}^{j-1}, \qquad 2 \le j \le d,
$$
where $X_{<j}$ denotes the vector containing the first $j-1$ coordinates of $X$.

I am wondering if this is a standard model in the literature or if it has a common name. Alternatively, is it a special case of some well known model?

More generally, we might have $X_{j}|X_{< j} \sim N(f_j (X_{<j}),~ \sigma^2_j)$ for some function $f_j:\mathbb{R}^{j-1}\to \mathbb{R}$, or potentially have the variance depent on $X_{<j}$ in a linear/non-linear way